# passenger + nginx fails when I disconnect from terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, rvm, passenger and nginx installed by passenger.
I connect to my server with Putty, start nginx via init.d/nginx and my Rails application works well.

But when I disconnect from terminal, I see standard application errors (Something went wrong, etc.).

nginx error log output:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
  from <internal:gem_prelude>:167:in `load_full_rubygems_library'
  from <internal:gem_prelude>:217:in `try_activate'
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:32:in `rescue in require'
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
  from /var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.18-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.6.3-1002/support/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:75:in `<main>'
*** Passenger ERROR (ext/common/ApplicationPool/../SpawnManager.h:220):
Could not start the spawn server: /home/torteg/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p320/ruby: No such file or directory (2)
*** Passenger ERROR (ext/common/ApplicationPool/../SpawnManager.h:220):
Could not start the spawn server: /home/torteg/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p320/ruby: No such file or directory (2)
```

ps aux output:

```
root      5066  0.0  0.0 220928  1936 ?        Ssl  15:46   0:00 PassengerWatchdog
root      5069  0.0  0.0 1872956 2340 ?        Sl   15:46   0:00 PassengerHelperAgent
root      5071  0.5  0.2 114348 10172 ?        Sl   15:46   0:00 Passenger spawn server
nobody    5074  0.0  0.1 169324  4688 ?        Sl   15:46   0:00 PassengerLoggingAgent
root      5105  0.0  0.0  39472  1028 ?        Ss   15:46   0:00 nginx: master process /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx
torteg    5106  0.0  0.0  39892  2276 ?        S    15:46   0:00 nginx: worker process
torteg    5116 13.2  1.5 225720 62432 ?        Sl   15:46   0:03 Passenger ApplicationSpawner: /webapps/ngt-storage
torteg    5132  2.4  1.5 230940 64520 ?        Sl   15:46   0:00 Rack: /webapps/ngt-storage
root      5141  0.1  0.1 160656  7272 ?        Ss   15:47   0:00 sshd: torteg [priv]
torteg    5145  0.0  0.0 164168  1820 ?        S    15:47   0:00 sshd: torteg [priv]
torteg    5291  0.0  0.0 160656  2656 ?        S    15:47   0:00 sshd: torteg@pts/3
```

Comment: News:
Created new user `deploy` with default bash shell. Installed rvm for this user. Then I set user and passenger_user to `deploy` in nginx.conf. Cleaned precompiled assets.. Works well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created new user **deploy** with default *bash* shell. Installed rvm for this user. Then I set user and passenger_user to **deploy** in nginx.conf. Cleaned precompiled assets.. Works well!

Answer (score 1):

So when you ssh into your production server, somewhere else in the world (or in the cloud) and you visit mydomain.com it works.  As soon as you log out of that ssh connection, nginx and passenger stop working? How are these two independent events tied to each other? 
What service are you using to host this app? 
Possible answer (will clean this up when you get answers to us)

I see you are using rvm too... unless the rvm path isn't set in your deploy user (just thinking out loud)

Comment: As soon as you log out of that ssh connection, nginx and passenger stop working? -  immediately. I use own server. torteg - is my user, which in nginx.conf. I installed rvm for torteg user.

Comment: do you have some weird setting in ssh that shuts everything down and only comes on if you ssh into it?  LIke does other things shut down too?

Comment: Also I use oh-my-zsh for `torteg` user.

Comment: do you have to log in as zsh or do you have your environment set to use zsh instead of bash?  it's quite possible that zsh kills itself and all processes with it (which may be the passenger one too) and nginx is set as root, probably (sudo) so it's unaffected.

Comment: Well an upvote at least is in order, I'd say :-), select your answer when it's time.